# Add to cart button not showing in product view pages

Tags: magento-1.9

In my Magento store add to cart option is showing only registered customers. 
the add to cart button is not showing the guest check out. what is the problem and how to solve this issue? I already enable the guest checkout is enabled in my admin panel.

I have used ebajes theme.

Comment: check in your theme product page setting.

Answer (score 1):

Please check product view or list files or condition in you theme which given in below link.

http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-hide-prices-and-add-to-cart-button-for-non-logged-in-visitors.html

So you can get proper idea.

Comment: I have checked in the above two links, but the code is not changed in my addtocart.phtml. any other options available pls tell me

Answer (score 1):

In the backend see which theme package and theme variant is applied. Then go to ap/design/frontend/your-theme-package/theme-variant/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml

There should be something like this to check if customer is logged in before add to cart button

```
if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()):
```

Directly uncomment this or create your theme variant copy the same folder structure and file and apply this from admin panel (if the your previous theme variant is default).